# Datejs get a string of days in a week

Tags: javascript, datejs

I use datejs, and I have two dates: `startDate` and `endDate`.

The dates are two objects of type date. I need to write a function that enumerates the days between these two dates.

the marge between is 7 days

Example:

```
startDate = 2012-10-30
endDate = 2012-11-05
```

I need to get a string of output like this:

`30,31,01,02,03,04,05`

Comment: Are you sure you need a *string* as output, not an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var getDays = function (start, end) {
    var days = [],
        temp = start.clone();

    while (temp <= end) {
        days.push(temp.toString('dd'));
        temp.add(1).day();
    }

    return days.join(',');
}

var days = getDays(Date.parse('2012-10-30'), Date.parse('2012-11-05'));
```

Returns a string such as `"30,31,01,02,03,04,05"`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
var startDate = new Date("2012-10-30"),
    endDate = new Date("2012-11-05"); // or whatever

var days = [];
for (var i=new Date(startDate); i<=endDate; i.setDate(i.getDate()+1))
    days.push(i.getDate());
```

To get that string you want, use

```
    days.push(("0"+i.getDate()).substr(-2));
```

instead, then `days.join(",")`.

As you are using date.js, here the above with some syntactic sugar:

```
for (var days=[], i=startDate.clone(); i<=endDate; i.addDays(1))
    days.push(i.toString("dd"));
return days.join();
```